# AttributeError: 'GlueContext' object has no attribute 'create_sample_dynamic_frame'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

This [official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context-create-sample-dynamic-frame-from-catalog) suggests there is a function to read sample data from Glue Catalog, which is create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog.

Detailed: create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog(database, table_name, redshift_tmp_dir, transformation_ctx = "", push_down_predicate= "", additional_options = {}, catalog_id = None)

But, when I try to use the same in my code, it errors out. I tried both of the below:

Option 1 (with dot before from_catalog as we generally do in reading dynamic frame - glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog):

```
AWSGlueDataCatalog_node1698294792048 = glueContext.create_sample_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="abc",
    table_name="def",
    transformation_ctx="ijk", sample_options = {'maxSamplePartitions':2, 'maxSampleFilesPerPartition': 3}
    )
```

**Error Message**: AttributeError: 'GlueContext' object has no attribute 'create_sample_dynamic_frame'

Option 2 (with all underscores):

```
AWSGlueDataCatalog_node1698294792048 = glueContext.create_sample_dynamic_frame_from_catalog(database="abc",
    table_name="def",
    transformation_ctx="ijk", sample_options = {'maxSamplePartitions':2, 'maxSampleFilesPerPartition': 3}
    )
```

**Error Message**: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o96.getSampleDynamicFrame. Trace:

What to do? My purpose is to read a small sample of a very big table to experiment on certain things without paying a lot on unnecessary processing of lot of data. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If you carefully look at the 'create_sample_dynamic_frame_from_catalog' definition in the [official document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context-create-sample-dynamic-frame-from-catalog), you will see the three mandatory parameters: database, table_name, num.

You have missed the 'num' parameter, which is the reason why you are getting the above error message.

I was able to create a sample dynamic frame using the below code:

```
df1 = glueContext.create_sample_dynamic_frame_from_catalog(
    database="default",
    table_name="test",
    num = 100,
    transformation_ctx="df1",
)
```

By following this, you will be able to create a sample dynamic frame and you can save a cost to process full data. :)